How to monitor the boot process for headless Jetson Orin via USB?
I've connected my Ubuntu 22 host to nru-220s-nvidia-jetson-orin via a USB-A to USB-C cable. I used Minicom to connect to /dev/ttyACM0, and that works OK.
I can also connect via SSH, so this USB connection does not bring anything new.
I'd like to use Minicom (or other tool?) also to monitor the Jetson boot process - is this possible at all? While booting, there is no /dev/ttyACM0 yet, until the boot is finished, so nothing to connect to.


While booting, there is no /dev/ttyACM0 yet, until the boot is finished, so nothing to connect to.

If this is the SoC's serial port, connected to a dedicated USB-UART device, you might be able to instruct your kernel to use the serial console instead of the graphical console for messages. Same for systemd. Look for serial console linux boot; you'll find a lot of articles.
If this is, however, just a USB gadget implemented by Linux, then, well, that only starts existing once the corresponding kernel module gets loaded.
The spec sheet and manual for the device don't give any indication as to what might be the case, so we can't tell you, either. You might need to ask the vendor, not us.

Thanks for your effort.
